# send images through java android sockets

Tags: java, android, sockets

I want to send images through sockets but I have not been able to do it in android, could someone help me?

```
System.out.println("iniciooooo");

        //converting image to bytes with base64
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/ajeffer.jpg");
        ByteArrayOutputStream byte2= new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,70,byte2);
        byte[] enbytes = byte2.toByteArray();
        String bb = Base64.encodeToString(enbytes,Base64.DEFAULT);
        System.out.println(Base64.encodeToString(enbytes,Base64.DEFAULT));
        data.writeUTF(bb);

        FileOutputStream file;

        //receiving the image in bytes to convert it into an image     
        DataInputStream dain = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        msg = dain.readUTF();
              
        File ff = new File("/sdcard/a2jeffer.jpg");
        byte[] deco = Base64.decode(dain.readUTF(),Base64.DEFAULT);
              
        Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(deco,0,deco.length);
               
        file = new FileOutputStream(ff);
        bit.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,70,file);
        //the image is not created
```

Comment: You don't need all this. `writeUTF()` can only send 64K characters, and the Base-64 encoding is pretty pointless anyway. Just send the bytes of the original image, or of the more-compressed image if you really must compress it further. You don't need the BitmapFactory at the receiving end either. Just standard Java copy loops at both ends.

Comment: I understand, and I think you are right, I found out that I had to get the bytes from the string but I have not managed to save it as an image, could you give me some example in code if it is not too much trouble

Comment: You don't need the string. Just copy the bytes direct. I've already stated all this.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that my code did not work because I had to put this `android: requestLegacyExternalStorage =" true "` in the manifest, also I see that you are right about writeUTF () since in order to send images I must drastically lower the quality but it works If you have an idea on how to improve this, let me know, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You were right, this works great for sending and receiving any file.

Send file

```
OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] datita = new byte[16*1024];
        int count;

        while((count = inputStream.read(datita))>0){
            outputStream.write(datita,0,count);
        }

        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
```

Receive file

```
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        InputStream inputStream = s.getInputStream();
                        byte[] datita = new byte[16*1024];
                        int count;

                        while((count = inputStream.read(datita))>0){
                            outputStream.write(datita,0,count);
                        }
                        outputStream.close();
                        inputStream.close();
```